# Как изменить переменную класса заданную в main функции в Python?

Tags: python

Набросал код для примера:

**test1.py**

```
import test2

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = ""

def changeTest(n):
    t.t = n
    print('change from test1 is - ', n)

t = Test()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t.t = "newnew"
    print('test', t.t)

    test2.newTest("new test 2")
    print('test 2', t.t)
```

**test2.py**

```
import test1

def newTest(t):
    test1.t.t = t
    print('change to - ', t)
    test1.changeTest(t)
```

вывод:

```
test newnew
change to -  new test 2
change from test1 is -  new test 2
test 2 newnew
```

как изменить t.t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас модуль `test1`  загружен два раза:

1. как `__main__` (основной скрипт)
2. как `test1` (импорт в test2)

Поэтому два разных глобальных объекта `Test()`, а `test2.newTest()` изменяет только один. Можно явно нужный объект импортировать:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from test1 import t
    t.t = 'in main'
    print(t.t)
    test2.newTest("in test2")
    print(t.t)
```

Лучше избегать глобального состояния и создавать, передавать явно нужные параметры:

```
def main():
    t = Test()
    test2.newTest(t, *etc)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Удалось решить данную проблем только явным импортом объекта t.

Answer (score 1):

Переменная t не меняется после исполнения модуля test2 потому, что функция которая в нем исполняется создает свою локальную область видимости, которую не видно из глобальной. Для того чтобы использовать результаты ее выполнения необходимо добавить возврат вычислений в конце функции (**return test1.t**), а в main добавить присвоение переменной этого результата (**t = test2.newTest("new test 2")**), пример:

test1.py

```
import test2


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = ""


def changeTest(n):
    t.t = n
    print('change from test1 is - ', n)


t = Test()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t.t = "newnew"
    print('test', t.t)

    t = test2.newTest("new test 2")
    print('test 2', t.t)
```

test2.py

```
import test1


def newTest(t):
    test1.t.t = t
    print('change to - ', t)
    test1.changeTest(t)
    return test1.t
```

Comment: это неверно. `test1.t.t = t` изменяет глобальную переменную в модуле `test1`. Проблема в том, что модуль под разными именами загружен (несколько модулей).